# Menu css con hover que despliege el background al tamaño del submenu

Tags: html, css

L o que necesito es que, cuando se haga hover en el menu dropdown y este se despliegue, el div contenedor del menu, en este caso es ul, reciba como minimo, la altura del submenu, expandiendo asì todo el contenedor hacia abajo. 
Pero es una cosa que no logro hacer.
Aqui el còdigo;

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

espero que me podais ayudar, un saludo

Comment: No comprendo muy bien lo que quieres conseguir. ¿Podrías detallarlo un poco mejor? Así será más sencillo el ayudarte.

Comment: He cambiado el contenido del post, es verdad que no esta muy claro. Lo siento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el css:

1) Esto quitalo: **position: absolute;**

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; /* Quitar */
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

2) Esto añadelo: **overflow-y: auto;**

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Añadir */
  background-color: #333;
}
```

Como en este ejemplo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/21a6pfcL/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Ahora ha quedado más claro.

El conseguir lo que necesitas es tan sencillo como cambiarle al elemento **.dropdown-content** de tu regla CSS, la propiedad **position** de **absolute** a **relative**. Quedando tu regla CSS así:

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Esto ocurre porque al tenerlo en **absolute**, no estaba generando un "espacio" a ocupar con el resto de elementos, al ponerle **relative** si que genera ese "espacio" por lo que al desplegarse hace crecer al **ul** por no tener este una altura fija.